# how to get last updated column name from mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to get a particular updated column name from a record?

if so, please help me. since i am creating a history table to store a updated column and their values from rest of the tables.

Please suggest me a correct way to deal this....

Comment: Either create triggers on all tracked tables or enable logging in server itself

Comment: Then each time that you make an UPDATE query you would do an INSERT query to the history table.

Comment: i have created a trigger but need a sub query like this( select LAST(COLUMN_NAME) from Table_Name; ) to get a particular updated column name witch is updated recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not possible.

However, you can create an update `trigger` which monitors the table's columns and have that trigger insert records in your history table. Hope this helps.

Comment: 6 answers in one day....that's quiet a start +1 !! :)

Comment: It is possible. Since OP didn't mentioned required method to do that, any solution is applicable. But logging is exactly the feature that is intended to do this work. Triggers are not the best choice (but - yes, are one of possible solutions)

Comment: @NoobEditor - I got plenty of time today. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

The only way for doing this is Using something like a **Log file**, in this case you will create a table that will contains the updated columns each time there is an update.

In this way you will be able to get the last record that will contains the **table_name** and the **column_name**.

And you can use a query looks like that:

```
select id, column_name, table_name 
from Log_table 
order by id desc
limit 1
```